# Scaling variables in homogeneous equation of degree two in a,b,c

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

The problem I'm having trouble with is:

Let $a,b,c$ be nonzero real numbers and let $a^2 - b^2 = bc$ and $b^2 - c^2 = ca$. Prove that $a^2 - c^2 = ab$.

The solution strategy given in the course was to scale the two given equations by $s=\frac{1}{c}$, resulting in $a^2 - b^2 = bc$ becoming $a^2 - b^2 = b$ and $b^2 - c^2 = ca$ becoming $b^2 - 1 = a$. I see that $c$ is basically being set to 1, but I don't understand the justification. Doesn't scaling by $\frac{1}{c}$ by definition not change the equations, since

$(a/c)^2 - (b/c)^2 = (b/c)(c/c) \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{a^2 - b^2}{c^2} = \dfrac{bc}{c^2} \Longleftrightarrow a^2 - b^2 = bc$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of this scaling as dividing all equalities by $c^2$, which is valid because $c\neq 0$. This division basically reduces a 3-variables problem into a 2-variables problem, which should be more tractable.

Let $A=a/c$, $B=b/c$ and $C=c/c=1$. Then, we have
$$
a^2-b^2=bc\implies A^2-B^2=B;\\
b^2-c^2=ca\implies B^2-1=A.
$$
It follows that
$$
A^2-1=(A^2-B^2)+(B^2-1)=B+A.
$$
Thus, it remains that we show $A+B=AB$. Note that
$$
B=A^2-B^2=A^2-(A+1)=A^2-A-1
$$
so
$$
AB=A+B\iff A^3-A^2-A=A^2-1\iff A^3-2A^2-A+1=0.\tag{i}
$$
To show that (i) holds, we use
$$
1+A=B^2=(A^2-A-1)^2=A^4-2A^3-A^2+2A+1
$$
which implies
$$
0=A^4-2A^3-A^2+A=A(A^3-2A^2-A+1).\tag{ii}
$$
Now we are done: (ii) implies that (i) is true, therefore we indeed have $AB=A+B$.